# Job Scheduling using Quartz.Net

Tags: .net, windows-services, quartz.net

I am scheduling Jobs as soon as a message arrive into our MSMQ.  This implementation is using the Quartz.Net API.

This Job is a simple trigger to be fired at certain time. One WinService is the client and other one is the server.

We get around 5000 msgs into our Queue and small percentage of them are failing in creating the Job. Below is the exception that I am getting:

```
at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.ValidateState()
at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.ScheduleJob(SchedulingContext ctxt,
  JobDetail jobDetail, Trigger trigger)
at Quartz.Impl.StdScheduler.ScheduleJob(JobDetail jobDetail, Trigger trigger)
```

Anyone out there used Quartz.Net?

Comment: Yes I'm using Quartz.Net. You only show the stack trace, but not the error message or the type of exception that you get.

Comment: this is all i see in my quartz log files when the client is trying to create the Job on the ADO JobStore.. is there any additional logging that I can turn on to capture the exception info.. i have the following logs for quartz.    <logger name="Quartz.Impl.*" writeTo="QuartzErrorOnly" level="Debug" />
    <logger name="Quartz.Impl.*" writeTo="QuartzTraceAndAbove" minlevel="Trace" />
    <logger name="Quartz.Core.*" writeTo="HistoryErrorOnly,HistoryMessageErrorOnly" level="Debug" />
    <logger name="Quartz.Core.*" writeTo="HistoryTraceAndAbove,HistoryMessageTraceAndAbove" minlevel="Trace" /

Comment: No exception message is very odd, and makes it nigh-impossible to debug.  Can you re-create this in test, if so you might want to run it as debug.

Comment: I've had success in running in debug and breaking on all CLR exceptions then seeing what's going on. Furthermore, you can download the source code and compile your own version of the DLLs to step through the code (I didn't manage to get it to associate the code with the PDB until I did this for some reason).